# AngularJs: After removing item from list, subsequent dirty form elements are set to pristine, how to handle this?

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have List of objects which I am iterating using ng-repeat.

List = [{
         type = "CC",
         cardNum : 125,
         accNum : null,
         amount =125,
         isCard : true
     },
     {
         type = "LN",
         cardNum : null,
         accNum : 125,
         amount =125,
         isCard = false
     },
....
]

Now, based on selection from Radio of isCard (two radio, is Card and is Non Card), I need to show two respective field such as cardNum or accNum.

Now the problem is, when iterate and add both combination of isCard and isNonCard account and remove element in between, all the elements after that are set to pristine where it was dirty before.

scenario 1:
 selected 1st as Card Acc - index 1
 2nd as Non Card  - index 2
 3rd as card acc  -index 3

touched the fields such that there is error for all 3 entries above

now, remove 2nd entry by using splice.

Issue: Now the 3rd element index is updated to 1(which is correct) but field is reset to pristine and error is hidden. How can I stop this so that error will still appear for 3rd element at updated index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue. Even after using track by index, it did not work so I had to add trackIdentifier in object. Now when I tracked based on it, it started working and error messages appeared correctly.